# How to get filenames when you drag'n'drop files from Finder on your app

Tags: swift, cocoa, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to let my NSView accept files which you can drag and drop from Finder.

I've already checked the documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/Tasks/acceptingdrags.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000993-BABHHIHC), but the only thing that works is accepting a drop of a String.

As the docs say, I have registered the types which can be dropped

```
func commonInit(){

    let allowedDropTypes = [NSFilenamesPboardType]

    registerForDraggedTypes( allowedDropTypes )

    Swift.print( registeredDraggedTypes )

}
```

If I print out the registeredDraggedTypes, I get `NSFilenamesPboardType`.

I've also implemented `draggingEntered(sender)`

```
override func draggingEntered(sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation {

    Swift.print("Dragging entered")

    return sender.draggingSourceOperationMask()

}
```

And `prepareForDragOperation(sender)` and `performDragOperation(sender)`

```
override func prepareForDragOperation(sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {

    Swift.print("Prepare for drag operation")

    return true

}

override func performDragOperation(sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {

    Swift.print("Perform for drag operation")

    return true

}
```

If I run my app, I can't drop any files from Finder on my app.

When I add `NSStringPboardType` to the array of allowed types, I can drag a piece of text on the app.  If I then try to add `NSPDFPboardType` to the array and drag a pdf on the app, it also doesn't work.

I've also tried working with the UTI `public.file-url`, but to no avail.

Also, app sandboxing is turned off.

I hope somebody can help me out :-)

Answer (score 3):

I found out what the problem was.

My NSView had NSImageViews as subviews and these were blocking the drag operation.
I've added an invisible NSView subview at the top and registered the drag operation on that view. Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to allow/add the filetypes you want in the Info plist of your project?

[example info plist file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SUPW.png)

I think you need to define the type of files you allow your application to open/handle, although not 100% sure if this is related to drag/drop. Worth a try at least.